# Change the "send code to interpreter" (C-c |) command in python-mode

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

I am used to "C-c C-r" command to send code to the interpreter in R with Emacs speaks statistics. How can I set python-mode to use "C-c C-r" rather than "C-c |" to evaulate code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already bound to `C-c C-r` in the built-in python.el, but here's a command that binds the key.  If you're using python-mode.el, you'll have to change the library name, the command, and maybe the map.

```
(eval-after-load "python"
  '(progn
     (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-r") 'python-shell-send-region)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am a begginer, so I dont know exactly where to do what you say? Do I have to add this command in .emacs?

Comment: Yes, put it in your ~/.emacs.  Personally, I like to make ~/.emacs.d and use ~/.emacs.d/init.el instead of ~/.emacs.

Comment: You can also put it in `*scratch*` and evaluate it with `C-M-x` or `C-x C-e`.